# How to split the datasets in folder wise in pytorch?

Tags: split, dataset, pytorch

There are 46 benign (B) patients and 44 malignant (M) patients. Each patient has 4 images. I want to take 60% patient as train, 20% as valid and 20% for test. The split should always have been done patient-level, meaning images of the same patient should either belong to the train or test set but not be shared among them.

So

> Train – B: 28 patients  + M: 26 patients ;
>       Valid- B: 9 patients  + M: 9 patients ;
>       Test- B: 9 patients  + M: 9 patients;

How to split the datasets in folder wise in pytorch?

Comment: what is the question here? randomly select the patients for each split, put them in `train`, `val` and `test` folders and make a `Dataset` object that reads the relevant images.

Comment: @Shai Thanks for your reply. I am new in pytorch. I already did what you said. But I want to take patient randomly each time.I don't want to fix the train, valid and test dataset.